# how do i hide the brackets and commas from the print statement?

Tags: python, string, printing

i'm trying to format this better so it prints out as one block of text (spaces are ok)

right now it's printing like this [4444, 4444] and i want it to print 4444 4444

```
#secret code encrypter 

def encoder(plain):
    '''encodes a given input with a secret formula
    '''
    result = []

    for i in plain:
        i=ord(i)*77+4
        result.append(i)

    return result 

def main():

    plain=input('Enter a sentence: ')
    final=encoder(plain)

    print(final)

main()
```

Comment: "encodes a given input with a secret formula" — no longer secret

Answer (score 7):

Make them strings and join them:

```
print(' '.join(map(str, your_list)))
```

Even better (if you're using Python 3.x) to avoid explicit conversion:

```
print(*your_list)
```

Comment: That second one is cool. Is that splat like Ruby's, or is it something else?

Comment: @Linuxios yup it's *splat*... `print` as a function takes a variable number of arguments so it's handy... Could use to print each on a new line for instance using `print(*your_list, sep='\n')` without looping or joining '\n's

Comment: I think you meant conversion instead of conversation, unless your python code is really talkative :-)

Comment: As a matter of style, list comprehensions are preferred over `map`. So sayeth Guido.

Answer (score 4):

If I get what your trying to do, try this:

```
print(" ".join(map(str, final)))
```

Comment: got an error. right now it's printing like this [4444, 4444] and i want it to print 4444 4444

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment to an earlier answer, you need this:

```
print(' '.join(str(x) for x in final))
```

This converts each of the elements in `final` to a string before joining them with a space between.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`print(" ".join(list_you_want_to_print))`

`str.join(iterable)` will return a string with the items in the utterable separated by the string.

Comment: @UpAndAdam, you're right. You can use `map(str, list_to_print)` to change everything to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Borrows from what others pointed out from my comments adds something many have missed that was previously in one of the answers:

1. (For pre python 3.0:) You will want to use `raw_input` instead of `input` because you just want to capture not evaluate.
   Per 2.7.5 docs:

   > `input(prompt)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`
2. Printing ( mostly lifted from Jon C's answer) Make them strings and
   join them:

   ```
   print(' '.join(map(str, your_list)))
   ```

   Even better (if you're using Python 3.x) to avoid explicit conversation:

   ```
   print(*your_list)
   ```